# Backslash at start of file path?

Tags: command-line, cd-command

When using the `cd` command at the terminal, I get a 'no such directory' error if I type something like

```
cd /directory/whatever/
```

But when I type something like

```
cd \directory/whatever/
```

It works just fine.

This occurs whether I am in the home directory or inside another directory.

What's more, this only seems to apply to directories like `Downloads`, `Pictures`, and the like, and also directories that I have created myself. Directories like `usr` and `etc` do not have this problem.

What could be causing this? and how can I change it to normal?

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! Please [edit] your question to add the output of the `pwd` command before and after you executed your `cd`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cd /directory/whatever/` uses **full pathname**, starting from top-most  directory `/`. Usually only users with root/sudo level of privilege can create directories there, so likely `directory` in `/` does not exist , hence the error.

`cd \directory/whatever/` uses **relative pathname** - relative to current working directory. Terminal starts out in user's home directory, aka `/home/$USER` aka same as what `pwd` or `echo $PWD` would report. Likely you've created `directory` and subdirectory `whatever` in your home directory. Equivalent would be `cd ./directory/whatever`, where `./` signifies current working directory link.

As for `\d` that uses the slash as escape character, which is here unnecessary but would be necessary in cases where filename contains special characters that shell treats as having different meaning. For example, `cd with\ space` and `cd 'with space'` are the same - one single string as argument to `cd`. By contrast, `cd with space` are two different strings given as arguments to `cd` (because unescaped spaces are treated as word separators in shell, aka word splitting) and of course it will result in an error

Comment: _“cd with space are two different strings given as arguments to cd (…) and of course it will result in an error”_ …not necessarily if you’re using Zsh. https://blog.confirm.ch/zsh-tips-changing-directories/

Comment: And of course    `cd "./directory with space/foo" `  takes care of whitespace in any shell.